# How to get process ID and deal with it using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

If one file is used by other process and you are trying to manipulate with it...it gives an error:-

> The process cannot access the file
>   'abc.txt' because it is being used by
>   another process.

In C#, How can i come to know that 'abc.txt' file is used by the process Name "XYZ.exe" (or any other process)?

Comment: What do you plan to do once you figure out what process is accessing it?

Comment: My scheduled console application runs after every set of time. If, somehow the file 'abc.txt'  is in use by other process (in this case XYZ.exe), i will stop the execution of my application and wait for next call.

Comment: Why do you need to know which process is accessing it? Just try to open the file for exclusive access, and if it fails, exit.

Comment: Oh..so you mean try catch... ?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search and think these posts can be helpful to you:

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019236/determine-which-process-blocks-a-file-programmatically-under-windows-xp/2019252)

[C# Answer#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-c)

[C# Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock-in-c)